# Outlook rule for a specific period date

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2013, rules

In my Outlook 2013, I am trying to manage my emails by creating sub-folders in my inbox.

What I want to do is to divide my emails in four sub folders named as follow :

(**First Quarter**, **Second Quarter**, **Third Quarter**, **Fourth Quarter**)

Currently, I want to apply this for the **First** and **Second** Quarter of the year.

Is it possible to do this by creating a specific rule?

I don't mind to create a rule for each quarter if needed.

Comment: So how many subfolders will you have? A never ending amount, such as `Q1 2015` `Q2 2015` `Q3 2015` `Q4 2015` `Q1 2016` `Q2 2016` `Q3 2016` `Q4 2016` etc or only 4 were all emails (regardless of year) go into that sub folder?

Comment: Actually I will move the four sub-folders later to a folder with year's name and archive it independently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, but you'd need to update the rule every quater

When you create a new rule, there is the option in Step 1

```
received in a specific date span
```

That will allow you to chose the date range you want to work with. In step 2 you can then choose

```
move to the specified folder
```

As per your comments, I'd probably create the sub folder now, similar to

```
2016
    Q3
    Q4
2017
    Q1
    Q2
    Q3
    Q4
2018
    Q1
    Q2
    Q3
    Q4
2019
    Q1
    Q2
    Q3
    Q4
```

And then (using the example above) create the rules required! This way you won't have to think about it until 2020!!